# input tag inside anchor tag with target _blank fires twice

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

In a html page, I added the following code

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><span><input type="button" value="google" /></span></a>
```

To achieve image button with sliding door technique, I happens to mark up like this.

Now when I click the button, google.com opens in two tabs in Firefox.

IE didn't respond at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is with your target attribute. Replace `_blank` with `__blank`.

Also replace your input button with an `<img>` tag

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="__blank">
     <img src="your_image_source" alt="Google" border="0" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks phoenix. 
I tried with type="image". That too not working. :-((
But I need input button there because my application requires it.

Comment: No I mean <img /> tag and not input type="image"

Comment: "__blank" solves my issue in Firefox even for <input type="button" />. But IE7 doesnot open any window at all???

Thanks Phoenix

Comment: If you nee the style of an input button then create an image that looks like an input button and use that inside the anchor tag.

Comment: I have done almost like that only. Please check the url
http://www.eduvisiontest.info/schoolsignin.aspx
I'm talking about Login button. Thoughout the site, i used this kind of markup. inside project at one place, i have to open a link when clicked this button.